# Flex Drag and Drop issue - right mouse click disables dragging

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air

I have a bordercontainer and several rectangle objects inside.

I can drag the objects inside the container, but when I right-click a rectangle and move the mouse while rmb is pressed, all dragging stops working. I have no idea why.

[image: sketch of problem]

Comment: Can you provide code for MOUSE_DOWN event you use?

Answer (score 0):

Right mouse button is reserved for the context menu. You can not change this. You can add to the context menu but you can not take it away. Clicking the right mouse button on your rectangle should bring up that context menu and stop all dragging. As far as I know, working as intended. If I am misunderstanding, please clarify and I will be happy to assist further if I can.

Comment: i can agree with that, right clicking shoudl bring context menu, but why it broke dragging, im dragging using left mouse click, and when i clicked right mb its all ok, BUT when i click and move while pressing RMB all dragging go to hell, why?

Comment: Hmmm... thats a new one to me. Cant say I have experienced that. So when dragging crap's out it is completely broken until you reload the page?

Comment: i need to restart application, its desktop app - i JUST ADDED SOME IMAGE - i hope it helps understand issue - i think its some flash bug

Comment: Looking at the image I fully understand now. Unfortunately, I have no idea what would cause that. Hopefully someone else can assist.